# How Do I Disable Google Search Autocorrect?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

I'm using Chrome right now and Google's auto-correct "feature" is really grating on my nerves. It's constantly merging two words into one and screwing with what I type. I don't care if I make a spelling error, but it **really** annoys me when the computer takes things into its own hands and "fixes" things that aren't mistakes.

How do I get it to just say "Did you mean?" instead of changing my search?

Comment: 'Autocorrect' from the Omnibox (address bar) in Google Chrome, or from Google.com?

Answer (score 1):

This userscript ([Disable Google Automatic Spelling Correction](http://www.web.archive.org/web/20131104004453/http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/103507)) might be helpful. It looks like it functions by adding `nfpr=1` as a URL parameter.

If that's all it is, you should be able to add a custom search engine which is just the same as a regular Google search but with the added parameter.

If it's your omnibar, though, I don't know that this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but this was irritating me, so I finally created a webpage to do it for me:  http://insteadfor.com.  It's very simple javascript; I'm not sure why it hasn't been done before.

I added it to my search bar for Firefox.  I'm not sure how you would do it in Chrome or other browsers.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest may to do that is doing it this way:

If it is Google Search results page do it this way:

```
    1. First Go into the Search box
    2. Then near your search type -(then the word that it autocorrects to),
    but if the autocorrected search is a sentence then type - for each word 
    in the sentence

 For an example:

 let's say you search something like "Yessle" (that is a new Search Engine)

For me it says "Yesstyle"

Then you go to the search box and then after "Yessle" type "-yesstyle" That should be fixed

  I was using that for an example
```